# Tableau display 3 measures in 1 column

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am building a report in Tableau with 4 fields. 3 of these fields are measure fields. This is what it looks like.

```
Name Sum Profit Loss
Emmy 15  10     5
Sara 23  18     2
Dave 10  1      2
```

But, I want it to look like this. I want a new column called metrics that pulls in those 3 values.

```
       Metrics
Emily  15
       10
       5
Sara   23
       18
       2
Dave   10
       1
       2
```

May I have some guidance on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is by bringing "Measure Names" to Rows
[image: Like this example]

You can hide the header names of the measures as well. hope that helps

Comment: If this has helped you, please mark as solved